# Jquery Multidimensional Array - how to loop each function?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, loops

I'm new to jQuery and hope someone can help me?

I have multidimensional array like this (please correct it if wrong)

```
var arr = {};
arr['AAA'] = {
                  'show':  'showTableA',
                  'txt' :  'txtHintA',
                  'url' :  'a.php'
             };
arr['BBB'] = {
                  'show':  'showTableB',
                  'txt' :  'txtHintB',
                  'url' :  'b.php'
             };
arr['CCC'] = {
                  'show':  'showTableC',
                  'txt' :  'txtHintC',
                  'url' :  'c.php'
             };
```

How to loop the function multidimensional array like this? I get it from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

```
function arr['AAA']['show'](str) {
   if (str=="") {
     document.getElementById(arr['AAA']['txt']).innerHTML="";
     return;
   }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
     document.getElementById(arr['AAA']['txt']).innerHTML=this.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", arr['AAA']['url']+"?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function BBB
function CCC
and so on ...
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Learn correct terminology. This is not a multi-dimension array. It's an object of objects. Your syntax `function arr['AAA']['show'](str)` has no chance whatsoever of working. What is it supposed to mean? Also, what does this have to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you modilfy slighly it will work. You can test after adding XmlHttpRequest.

```js
var arr = {};
    arr['AAA'] = {
        'show':  'showTableA',
        'txt' :  'txtHintA',
        'url' :  'a.php'
    };
    arr['BBB'] = {
        'show':  'showTableB',
        'txt' :  'txtHintB',
        'url' :  'b.php'
    };
    arr['CCC'] = {
        'show':  'showTableC',
        'txt' :  'txtHintC',
        'url' :  'c.php'
    };

    console.log(arr);

    function showTable(key, str) {
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById(arr[key]['txt']).innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        /*xmlhttp = new XmlHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                document.getElementById(arr[key]['txt']).innerHTML=this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", arr[key]['url']+"?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();*/

        document.getElementById(arr[key]['txt']).innerHTML=str;
    }

    $.each( arr, function( key, value ) {
        showTable(key, "test");
        console.log( key + ": " + value );
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="txtHintA"></p>
    <p id="txtHintB"></p>
    <p id="txtHintC"></p>
</body>
</html>
```